# Angular/Jest unit testing with Mapquest API

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs, mapquest

I am using mapquest api through CDN and have it declared as "declare let L: any;" in my typescript code. When I try to write unit tests and run the test suite I get an error "ReferenceError: L is not defined".

I am using Angular 8 and Jest as test runner. Please let me know, how to include the declaration in the unit tests. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Angular at all, but if you declare L as a global variable, does the test suite still get the error?

Does the map display as expected despite the test suite error?

L is the global Leaflet variable. MapQuest.js is based on Leaflet.

Comment: currently I am skipping the test for that component.